# Pandas: how to treat strange time format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following Pandas dataframe, where the time (duration) is given in a very strange format:

```
Person   Activity   Duration
1        A          1 00:00
2        A          1 00:00
3        B          0 21:17
4        C          0 17:11
```

Where `1 00:00` means 24 hours, and `0 21:17` means 0 days and 21:17 hours, which is to say just 21:17 hours. A quick look at the dtypes returns:

```
In[1]: df.dtypes
Out[1]: 
Person         object
Activity       object
Duration       object
dtype: object
```

How can I consistently treat the `Duration` column to return 24 if the value is `1 00:00`, and the decimal value of the duration if I have `0 21:17`? The decimal value of `0 21:17` would be 21.283.

The outcome should be:

```
Person   Activity   Duration
1        A          24
2        A          24
3        B          21.283
4        C          17.183
```

Comment: Do you have data like `1 12:34`

Comment: Nope, the maximum is 1 00:00, eg 24 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned that it wont go beyond 1 00:00 that is 24:00, there is a simpler way:

```
'''
Person  Activity    Duration
1   A   1 00:00
2   A   1 00:00
3   B   0 21:17
4   C   0 17:11
'''

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_clipboard("\t")
```

.

```
   Person Activity Duration
0       1        A  1 00:00
1       2        A  1 00:00
2       3        B  0 21:17
3       4        C  0 17:11
```

.

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].str.split(' ')

df['Duration'] = ['24:00' if int(val[0]) == 1 else val[1] for val in df['Duration']]

print(df)
```

.

```
   Person Activity Duration
0       1        A    24:00
1       2        A    24:00
2       3        B    21:17
3       4        C    17:11
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = np.array([24, 1, 1/60])    
df.Duration = df.Duration.str.split(' |:', expand=True).astype(int).dot(a)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': [1,2,3,4], "Activity": list('AABC') ,"Duration":['1 00:00', '1 00:00', '0 21:17', '0 17:11']})
df.Duration = df.Duration.str.split(' |:', expand=True).astype(int).dot(a)
print(df)
#   Person Activity   Duration
#0       1        A  24.000000
#1       2        A  24.000000
#2       3        B  21.283333
#3       4        C  17.183333
```

Comment: curved brackets missing
```a = np.array([24, 1, 1/60])```

Answer (score 2):

You can just multiply and add these numbers together easily:

```
durations = [   
    "1 00:00",
    "0 21:17",          
]                                                                        

for duration in durations: 
    day, clock = duration.split()
    hour, minute = clock.split(':')
    print((int(day) * 24) + int(hour) + (int(minute) / 60))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go with the datetime module for time conversion

```
from datetime import datetime
def durationInDecimal(string):
    day, time = string.split(" ")
    t = datetime.strptime(time, "%H:%M").time()
    return int(day)*24 + (t.hour+t.minute/60.0)


df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': list("ABCD"), "Activity": list('ABCD') ,"duration":['1 00:00', '1 00:00', '0 21:17', '0 17:11']})
df["duration"] = df.duration.apply(durationInDecimal)

# Person    Activity    duration
# 0 A   A   24.000000
# 1 B   B   24.000000
# 2 C   C   21.283333
# 3 D   D   17.183333
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other helpful answers, I wanted to post my own solution, which uses a custom function and applies it to a dataframe using `df.apply`:

```
def custom_time_to_decimals(value):
    if value.split()[0]=='1':
        return 24
    else:
        custom = value.split()[1]
        hours = int(custom[0:2])
        minutes = int(custom[3:5])
        decimal = hours + (minutes/60)
        return round(decimal,3)

df['decimalHours'] = df['<insertYourTimeColumnHere>'].apply(custom_time_to_decimals)
```